# Live update index in production database

Tags: sql-server, index, index-tuning

I have read [Perform Index Operations Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/perform-index-operations-online?view=sql-server-2017) provided by MSFT but I couldn't find any detail information for my questions.

My questions are:

- What is the impact when I update (create/drop) non-clustered index in the live database?
- If the database cannot be shut down, is there any specific way to reduce the risk and impact?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE and thanks for participating. Your question isn't really clear, as `update` is not the same as `create/drop`. A `REBUILD` could be viewed as a `drop/create` and a `REORGANIZE` would be just shuffling the index leaf pages around on disk. Could you clarify your question a bit please?

Comment: I have added the mentioned page link to your post. I hope it is the correct link? Otherwise please change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean But during index creation/updating period, will they cause
>   data corruption because old index cannot be found

None of the documented `T-SQL commands` can cause `data corruption`.

The difference between `online` and `offline` index operations is in the fact of index's availability: while you do them online, indexes are still available, and when offline, they are not.

This means that your queries just cannot use `nonclustered index` for a period of its `rebuild offline`, and in case of `clustered index` `rebuild` the whole table is not available when doing it `offline`.

`Online` index operations come at a cost: they are slower, they are `fully logged` (while `offline` rebuild can be `minimally logged` if your db's recovery model is `simple`/`bulk logged`), and `online` index rebuild can result in long time blocking under some conditions described here: [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (8/30) unicorns, rainbows, and online index operations by Paul randal](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-830-unicorns-rainbows-and-online-index-operations/)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you dropping and recreating the indexes?  You should be reorganizing or rebuilding them.  Online if you have Enterprise and want to.

You can disable the index during ETL operations if you need to as well, just rebuild afterwards.

Impact of your approach:
 - Schema locks while index is being built.
 - Potential blocking while index is being built.
 - Larger than necessary I/O
 - Any queries that use index hints will break while the index is
   dropped.

Comment: But after indexes creation and deletion complete, all queries should run with new reference right?

Comment: Yes, after it's created, the engine should start using the index if it's appropriate for the query.

Comment: But during trigger creation/updating period, will they cause data corruption because old index cannot be found or basically just introduce delay which is not a very serve issue.

Comment: triggers are a different animal.  they require an X lock on the table (during creation) so have to wait for writes to quell.  And depending on what the trigger is doing, then you may have some data oddities.  with indexes, usually the worst you get is bad performance on reads if they aren't there.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I mean But during tindex creation/updating period, will they cause data corruption because old index cannot be found or basically just introduce delay which is not a very serve issue.

Comment: There will be no data corruption because the index cannot be found, just slowness because the index isn't ready, available or being rebuilt.